# jquery plugin defaults with ajax.load

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im creating a jQuery (ajax.load) plugin which triggers the plugin based on a set data-attribuut. The value of this attribute overwrites the default setting.
All works fine, but:

1) if the value is kept empty, the empty value overwrites my defaults, which i dont want.

The only way I can prevend this now, is by doing this while setting the options object:

```
content_url_el: $(element).find('a[data-attribute]').attr('data-attribute') || 'content'.
(where content is the default value.)
```

There must be a better way for this so i can use my default setting in:

```
$.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
   content_url_el: 'content', // class element on url to get content from.
 };
```

2) If the content_url_el, which is the class in the loaded ajax-page, is not found, is there a way to check this. In the ajax.response the whole page is returned, not only the content in the class element and thereby ajax status = success.

Thanks for your help.